# Infinite loop in main()

Tags: c

Why does calling `main()` inside the body of `main()` cause an finite loop?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("\n Sonata Software");
    main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or, "recursion".  It will run until the stack is depleted.  Why wonder?  Try it.

Comment: main is just a function. You can call the same function within itself, it is called recursion. You should search this stuff in the search bar before asking simple questions.

Comment: It's not infinite because it will blow the stack within a few cycles

Comment: no..it is a finite loop...it will stop after sometime....do watch the output carefully

Comment: elias .....if it's recursion why it doesn't run infinite

Comment: @user3699872 if you had an infinite computer, it would.

Comment: The close-duplicate is wrong. The question is in fact a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213216/infinite-loop-in-main).

Comment: @KerrekSB Not really.  The user posted the question twice.  They are both duplicates of the properly listed question.

Answer (score 0):

This "loop" terminates or is "finite" because you keep calling `main()` from within `main()`, eventually using up all the stack frame space you have and resulting in a `StackOverflow`

Answer (score 0):

This program will not run. Main is not a userdefined function, that you'll call it as function within main as recursion. It'll show some error.

Comment: The rules for C and C++ are different; C allows (or at least, doesn't explicitly forbid) calling `main` from within the program.